# % iowait increase at 99.9% from specific time

Tags: 12.04, server

% iowait increase at 99.9% from specific time, which make slow performance of server, kindly let me know solution to fix?

```
08:30:01  IST     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
08:45:01  IST     all      0.01      0.00      0.02     99.96      0.00      0.00
09:00:01  IST     all      0.02      0.00      0.03     99.95      0.00      0.00
09:15:01  IST     all      0.03      0.00      0.03     99.93      0.00      0.00
09:30:01  IST     all      0.01      0.00      0.02     99.97      0.00      0.00
09:45:01  IST     all      0.04      0.00      0.06     99.91      0.00      0.00
10:00:01  IST     all      0.05      0.00      0.04     99.90      0.00      0.00
Average:        all      0.02      0.00      0.03     18.84      0.00     81.11
```

Answer (score 2):

Install `iotop` to see which processes exhaust your I/O.

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
```

You have to run it as a superuser:

```
sudo iotop
```

[image]

See https://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/linux-iotop-simple-top-like-io-monitor/ for details on how to install and use it.